# How to place label inside the span element wpcf7-form-control-wrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I would like to put the label for input elements inside the span element generated by the cf7 shortcode - is thi spossible?

The reason I want to do this is that I am trying to make the label only appear when the input field has :focus

In order to do this the label and the input need to be inside the same element so I can target with the following css selector:

## input-ID:focus + .label-class

I have tried just pasting the generated HTML markup into CF7 and moving the label inside (rather than using the shortcode) which acheives what I want, however it causes a strange problem where the "required" attribute no longer works - all fields are required but the form can now be submitted empty

This is what CF7 Generates:

```html
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name-wrap">
<input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" id="your-name-1" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Name"></span>
<label for="your-name" class="label-helper">Name</label>
```

This is what I want:

```html
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name-wrap">
<input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" id="your-name-1" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Name">
<label for="your-name" class="label-helper">Name</label></span>
```

I've tried implementing the HTML above rather than using CF7 shortcode but required no longer works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check it may it will help. I think you used in each function or through loop..

```js
var getLabel = $(".wpcf7-form-control-wrap").next("label").detach();
        $(".wpcf7-form-control-wrap").append(getLabel);
```

```css
.wpcf7-form-control:focus + .label-helper{color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap your-name-wrap">
<input type="text" name="your-name" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" id="your-name-1" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="Name"></span>
<label for="your-name" class="label-helper">Name</label>
```

Comment: Thank you - I can see this works if I manually input the HTML (rather than use CF7 shortcodes)... But for some reason if I use shortcodes to generate the form field - then this jquery doesnt work (I added to the head of the page) - Any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
    var spans = document.getElementsByClassName("wpcf7-form-control-wrap");
    for(var i=0;i<spans.length;i++)
    {
        var input = spans[i].nextSibling;
        if(input != null)
        {
            if(input.tagName == "LABEL")
            {
                spans[i].appendChild(input);
            }   
        }   
    }
```